# Resubscribe to Kafka-topic and get only new messages

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I'm building an application where I need to subscribe and unsubscribe Kafka topics on the fly. Problem is I can't find a way to resubscribe the topic so that I only get new messages of that topic that occur after the subscription.

When setting `"auto.offset.reset": "latest"` I get only new messages on the first subscription but not on the later ones.

Should I maybe create a new consumer group each time I need to subscribe to a new topic?

**Update:**

I tried setting up the consumer like this which is correct way to do it but problem was I had already committed offsets with my groupId. Problem was solved by changing the groupId.

```
c, err := kafka.NewConsumer(&kafka.ConfigMap{
    "bootstrap.servers":  os.Getenv("KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS"),
    "group.id":           "foobar",
    "enable.auto.commit": false,
    "auto.offset.reset":  "latest",
})
```

Comment: Auto offset only applies on the first subscription of a new group, anyway... Not sure I fully understand the issue since committing the offsets, then resuming the consumer at any point in the same group would provide exactly what you want (new messages after from where you stopped)... Can you please show the code?

Comment: Thanks for reply! My question is then can I somehow "reset" the offset so that when I resubscribe to a topic I only get the new messages. I'm writing a service that only listens to certain topics few times a day for couple of minutes max and I'm not interested about messages that occur between those periods. I don't think sharing the code would help here but logic is: 1. subscribe topic 2. unsubscribe if receiving message with correct values 3. subscribe again when getting trigger and looping this for multiple different topics. Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "new". Is that always from the very end of the topic? Or events immediately after the most recent consumed event? Specifically, I wanted to see your consumer config that sets `auto.offset.reset` as well as `enable.auto.commit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the key part that needs to be considered when you use consumer group offset tracking

> listens to certain topics few times a day for couple of minutes max... not interested about messages that occur **between those periods**

To always have your consumer "tail" the topic,  set `enable.auto.commit=false` along with `auto.offset.reset=latest`, and don't commit offsets at all

Otherwise, `seekToEnd()` is the consumer method you want

Comment: Thanks! I had tried those configs but the problem was I had already committed offsets with the same groupId for the topic.